# Access CFS from a Spark application

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to read from and write to my local cfs installation which I accomplished by installing DSE locally, in standalone mode.

My guess is that, in order to connect to the cfs, I somehow have to use the `right` host name, and by `right` I mean the one utilized by the Spark master (in order to create the spark context) when I do `./dse spark`.

Should be fairly easy but I can't figure out how... Any ideas?

Comment: Did you start your local node with spark enabled ? Did you see Spark running from the browser ?

Comment: yes it runs ok with `./dse spark`

Comment: updated my question in order to make clearer what I am trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access your cfs using a relative path, as in a hadoop env.
sc.textFile("/yourpath")

EDIT

Ok, so probably you need to specify also the driver host to enable communication with master.

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
    .set("spark.driver.host", "driver ip")
    .setMaster("master host name")

val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Comment: nope. I am not asking how to access it while in e.g. REPL mode. But in fact, I am asking how to setup the spark context - as part of external spark/scala application that I try to build - in order to access that (same) resource...

Comment: ok cool. can it be the case that both "driver ip" and "master host name" are "127.0.0.1"? should I use "http://" on the front? should I refer to the ports somehow as well?

Comment: for the driver you need only to specify the ip. Instead for master you need to have a schema like this spark://masterHostName:7077.